# AG-Grid with Angular2. Error while installing the ag-grid in angular2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm new to angular2. In my basic angular2 project I trying to place ag-grid. I'm getting error

```
node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/lib/ng2ComponentFactory.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module 
'"C:/practice/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler/index"' has no exported member 'RuntimeCompiler'.
```

package.json

```
    "ag-grid": "6.4.x",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "6.4.x",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "6.4.x",
```

systemjs.config.js

```
'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid',
'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2'

packages: {
      'ag-grid-ng2': {
        defaultExtension: "js"
      },
      'ag-grid': {
        defaultExtension: "js"
      },
    }
```

app.module.ts

```
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    AgGridModule.withNg2ComponentSupport(),
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the app.module.ts file, withNg2ComponentSupport() it getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your message I'm guessing you're using angular 2 2.3+ - if so, then the problem is that ag-grid-ng2 6.x does not support this version.

Angular 2 made the RuntimeCompiler non-public (well, moved it etc) which ag-grid-ng2 relied on.

If you want to use Angular 2.3+ then you'll need to upgrade to ag-grid-ng2 7.x, which supports it

Comment: There is any demo project angular2+ag-grid with basic example i think it will help me.

Comment: The https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example repo has many examples you can look at, with examples with webpack, systemjs and angular-cli

Comment: thanks @SeanLandsman. i'm new to these topic instead of total repo can i get the basic one so that i can learn it and use the basic one in my project.